# Pygame Infinite World Generation Broken

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making a basic 2D platformer game with the pygame module in python. Recently I've been trying to implement infinite world generation, but have been having some problems. The generation works fine, however, at the player's spawn, a bunch of random tiles spawn, obstructing the whole spawn area. I can't seem to find what's causing this.
Here's everything you need to replicate my situation:

map generation:

```py
def generate_chunk(x,y):
    chunk_data = []
    for y_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
            target_x = x * CHUNK_SIZE + x_pos
            target_y = y * CHUNK_SIZE + y_pos
            tile_type = 0 # nothing
            if target_y > 10:
                tile_type = 2 # dirt
            elif target_y == 10:
                tile_type = 1 # grass
            elif target_y < 10:
                tile_type = 0
            if tile_type != 0:
                chunk_data.append([[target_x,target_y],tile_type])
    return chunk_data
...

while True:
...
tile_rects = []
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(4):
            target_x = x - 1 + int(round(scroll[0]/(CHUNK_SIZE*16)))
            target_y = y - 1 + int(round(scroll[1]/(CHUNK_SIZE*16)))
            target_chunk = str(target_x) + ';' + str(target_y)
            if target_chunk not in game_map:
                game_map[target_chunk] = generate_chunk(target_x,target_y)
            for tile in game_map[target_chunk]:
                display.blit(tile_index[tile[1]],(tile[0][0]*16-scroll[0],tile[0][1]*16-scroll[1]))
                if tile[1] in [1,2]:
                    tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(tile[0][0]*16,tile[0][1]*16,16,16))
```

full code:
https://github.com/nice-404/Platformer

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the random tile spawning.
[image: example of random tile spawning]

[image: what is everywhere else, and is supposed to be at the spawn]

(I have been following DaFluffyPotato's platformer tutorial series because I am new to pygame)

Comment: Please don't just post a link to your project; create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the emphasis on _minimal_. 200 LOC is too much for most people to analyze.

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski Sorry, I've edited this now

Comment: Are the tiles random in that their positions change every time you run the code?

Comment: One issue I can see is the check `if tile != '3' or tile != '0':` which is always true. You'll want either `if not (tile == '0' or tile == '3')` or `if tile != '0' and tile != '3'` (which are equivalent). But that should only affect collision detection, not drawing.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that could mess up the collisions, and the tiles aren't random, I'm trying to start with basic code that just creates an infinite flat platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of debugging and further looking into the chunk generating code, I couldn't find out anything. However, I did figure out that the issue only happened in a small area, at the 0 x value. So what I did was I made the player spawn very far away from this, and made a boundary so that it couldn't walk far enough to see the issue. Not really fixing the issue, but at least it works now.